# React & TypeScript - Conditional argument type if props is present

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker, dayjs

In react I'm trying to set a conditional type in a function argument depending if a prop is pass in the component.

Here is the example, I have this component:

```
const DatePicker = ({
  handleDateChange,
  value,
  objectKey,
}: {
  handleDateChange: (value: Dayjs | { [x: string]: Dayjs }) => void;
  value: Dayjs;
  objectKey?: string;
}) => JSX
```

What I want to do is that, if "objectKey" is pass as props than the type of the paremeter "value" in the function **handleDateChange** would be { [x: string]: Dayjs }, otherwise it would be **value: Dayjs**.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make this?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something like this with [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

```js
// first overload signature
function DatePicker({
  handleDateChange,
  value,
}: {
  handleDateChange: (value: Dayjs) => void;
  value: Dayjs;
}): JSX;
// second overload signature
function DatePicker({
  handleDateChange,
  value,
  objectKey,
}: {
  handleDateChange: (value: { [x: string]: Dayjs }) => void;
  value: Dayjs;
  objectKey?: string;
}): JSX;
// implementation
function DatePicker({
  handleDateChange,
  value,
  objectKey,
}: {
  handleDateChange: ((value: Dayjs) => void) | ((value: { [x: string]: Dayjs }) => void);
  value: Dayjs;
  objectKey?: string;
}) {
  // ...
}
```

With this approach `DatePicker` can only be *called* according to your definition, however the implementation won't know the correlation between `handleDateChange` and `objectKey` so you still need to handle that explicitly.

Without knowing any details of `DatePicker` I think it would be better to only use one signature and let the parent component make changes to fit `DatePicker` instead of having `DatePicker` handle special cases from it's parents.

Comment: Function unions like this are nearly impossible to call, however: https://tsplay.dev/mbabEN

Answer (score 1):

The following type should do what you are interested in, using [Unions and Intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html):

```
type DatePickerProps = {
    value: Dayjs;  
} & ({
    objectKey?: undefined;
    handleDateChange: (value: Dayjs) => void;
} | {
    objectKey: string;
    handleDateChange: (value: { [x: string]: Dayjs }) => void;
});
```

Explanation:

- Since `value` is always part of the type, we add it first to get it out of the way, and so that we don't duplicate it.
- Then we intersect (`&`) that part with the union (`|`) of the two situations that can vary according to your rules, specifically:
- The signature of `handleDateChange` varies based on whether the type of `objectKey` is `string` or `undefined` (not set).
- We define `objectKey` differently (first with `?`, then without) because we want to let TypeScript know it is completely omittable when not set.

You can simply assign it to the props parameter object:

```
const DatePicker =
    ({handleDateChange, value, objectKey}: DatePickerProps) =>
        ...
```